# How to fetch data with total count using mysql single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to write one mysql query to fetch all my table data and with total records count.

For eg. this is my table

```
ID     Name    typeId
1      test1   1
2      test2   1
3      test3   2
```

If I am going to fetch data with type id 1 I need a result like this

```
Name    count 
test1   2
test2   2
```

How can I write sql for this kind of a result. 
I dont want subquery. I want to fetch data with out subquery
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Is the count just the number of records in the table, or, of something else?

Comment: Your edited example doesn't seem to make any sense. Did you perhaps mean to put `typeId` instead of `Name` in the output? Anyway, why is the count equal to 2 in *both* cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your desired result this is a bizarre requirement as you want all count(not for each `Name`). You can use sub-query for that:

```
SELECT `Name`, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable) as `COUNT`
FROM myTable
```

Or if you want count for each `Name` try this:

```
SELECT `Name`, COUNT(*) AS `COUNT` 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY `Name`;
```

**EDIT:**

As you have updated your question your query should be like this:

```
SELECT `Name`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE TypeId = 1 GROUP BY TypeId) as `COUNT`
FROM myTable WHERE TypeId = 1;
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65953/5)

Comment: @learner. Updated the answer. But remember, Always be clear before asking a question. Please don't change your requirement as you did in this question. If you do this, all given answers will become wrong for updated question.

Comment: Hi with out using subquery can u fetch same result data?

Comment: @learner Looking at your requirement, I don't think without sub-query it is possible. [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65953/10)

Answer (score 2):

alternatively is to use `CROSS JOIN` here

```
SELECT name, c.totalCount   
FROM Table1, (SELECT COUNT(*) totalCount FROM Table1) c
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3f19/7)

Comment: Please check my updated question. I dont want subquery. I want to fetch data with out subquery

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,count(*) as count from tablename where typeid=1 group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, count(*) AS count FROM <TABLE NAME> GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*, count(\*) AS count FROM myTableName as t GROUP BY t.Name;
```