# MySQL Performance: SELECT with inner query vs CROSS JOIN (returning COUNT with data in same query)

Tags: mysql, sql

RE these two answers to an old question:
[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703322/how-to-fetch-data-with-total-count-using-mysql-single-query/12703417#12703417),
[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703322/how-to-fetch-data-with-total-count-using-mysql-single-query/12703472#12703472).

I have a query which selects 14 columns and uses 10 LEFT JOINs, which I've attempted to simplify below.  I'm hoping to be able to return the total results COUNT (irrespective of LIMIT/OFFSET) as part of the same query.

**My question: is there a dramatic performance difference depending on which of the two answers I employ or are they pretty much doing the same thing?**

e.g. Answer 1

```
SELECT
a.id,
b.name AS course,
DATE_FORMAT(a.start_date,'%d %M %Y') AS start_date,
DATE_FORMAT(a.end_date,'%d %M %Y') AS end_date,
/* MANY MORE FIELDS IN SELECT STATEMENT */,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM courses AS a /* LEFT JOINs & WHEREs */) AS count,
FROM courses AS a
/* MANY LEFT JOINS */
WHERE
a.start_date > CURRENT_DATE(),
/* A FEW MORE WHERE STATEMENTS */
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 15
```

or Answer 2

```
SELECT
a.id,
b.name AS course,
DATE_FORMAT(a.start_date,'%d %M %Y') AS start_date,
DATE_FORMAT(a.end_date,'%d %M %Y') AS end_date,
/* MANY MORE FIELDS IN SELECT STATEMENT */,
z.count
FROM courses AS a
/* MANY LEFT JOINS */,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM courses AS a /* LEFT JOINs/WHEREs */) AS z
WHERE
a.start_date > CURRENT_DATE(),
/* A FEW MORE WHERE STATEMENTS */
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 15
```

Right now with a handful of test records there's no difference but I wonder if there's a simple YES/NO for when we're returning 100s or 1000s of records?

Comment: You should test with a larger data set, but also try using `EXPLAIN` to see if any notable differences stand out.  I think an exact answer would be difficult based only on the information you gave.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance of inner join compared to cross join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join)